# Windows subsystem for Linux Bash - How to page up and down?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The title says it all.  Maybe its just my laptop, but I am running Ubuntu 16.04 for WSL and no combination of keys allows me to page up or down.  I have tried every combination of Ctrl, Shift, PgUp, PgDn, and the arrow keys.

Comment: Go vote for it:  https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a way to do it in the standard Windows console, I haven't found it. I've switched to [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), and Ctrl-PgUp and Ctrl-PgDn work. Ctrl-UpArrow and Ctrl-DownArrow work too.

ConEmu has numerous other benefits; color themes and better cut-and-paste to name a couple of my favorites. You can run WSL bash, cmd, PowerShell, Cygwin, and more in ConEmu.

Comment: Though this doesn't directly answer the question, ComEmu is the best Windows utility I have found in the past 5 years and I thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

Install [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701). It's a very good replacement for the Windows console. Open its settings, Add these lines to `actions` sections:

```
{ "command": "scrollUpPage", "keys": "shift+pageup" },
{ "command": "scrollDownPage", "keys": "shift+pagedown" },
```

Comment: This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This totally fixed the problem for me (WSL on Windows 11 using Ubuntu):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ultimate-bashrc/files/

(note that I attempted to copy a keymap first, /etc/default/us.map.gz, which didn't fix anything - not sure if this .bashrc fixed the problem, or, it caused my keymap fix to fix it)

Probably it will just fix it though.

Answer (score -1):

YOu can set Properties → Layout → Screen Buffer Size → Height on the number of lines you want.

Give a higher value of about 9999